# Python IDLE refuse to launch

Tags: python-3.7

Python Idle recently straight up refuse to launch, launching it from start menu or its own folder does nothing. Repairing and reinstalling does nothing, nor does running it in older versions of windows does anything.
No changes were made to the program before this. It could be due to a windows update but highly doubted it.
normally, I would get error messages or something. But nothing this time, it doesn't even show up in task manager.

Comment: What version are you trying to use?

Comment: Python 3.7.1, the latest version downloaded from python site.

Comment: Have you tried a previous version to see if it works? Also make sure you have the correct version (x64 or x86)

Comment: Previous version stopped working, so I uninstalled that and downloaded the latest version from their site.

Comment: Try deleting the idlerc folder in your profile directory e.g. C:\Users\your-username

Comment: seems like that fixes it, thank you. Weird problem.

Comment: I submitted it as an answer to make it clear to others with the same problem of the answer. Please upvote/accept to approve it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the idlerc folder in your profile directory.
This should fix the problem

Example folder directory:

> C:\Users\your-username